# Release input automatically in vmware

Tags: mouse, vmware

Player grabs the input when clicked inside, then the mouse pointer is locked within the Player window and I have to press ctrl+alt for the Player to release input.

Previously it all worked automagically, a few days ago, and I haven't changed the host (11.10) or guest (win XP) OSs or anything drastic like that.  Maybe I have accidentally bumped some keystroke which disables the mouse pointer integration ?

I can't find the setting to make it go back to how it used to work..

Comment: VMPlayer version 4.0.1 build-528992, VMWare tools 8.8.1, host OS 3.0.0-15-generic

Comment: Try to recompile VMWare tools for your Kernel by running `sudo vmware-config.pl`

Comment: `vmware-config.pl` is not on my machine.  i have `/usr/lib/vmware/setup/vmware-config` but it gives me a usage message: 
`Usage: /usr/lib/vmware/setup/vmware-config [--get KEY] [--set KEY VALUE] [--sh]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't provide any more information, but my problem simply went away after rebooting.  Maybe it was a bug in VMWare.

Comment: i have the same problem and rebooting didn't help